# MVC Razor use ViewBag as part of dynamic Image link

Tags: image, razor, model-view-controller, viewbag

I've got an MVC Application and I've got a ViewBag List of Items.  I've got the List using Razor to show in a Modal popup and I was hoping to use said list, to dynamically display an image for each item in the list

I'm hoping for something along the lines of "~/Images/ + @ViewBag.List[i] + .jpg"

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this as I've not had much luck so far?

Any assistance on accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance
Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.List)
{
   <img src="~/images/@(item).jpg" />
}
```

Should work for you.  The issue you were running into is you do not need the:

```
+ @ViewBag.List[i] +
```

@ViewBag.List[i] will work inline without any string concatenation.

Comment: Greatly Appreciated, just goes to show that theres more than one way to do things, I was originally using:  for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.SoftwareList.Count; i++).  this was fine for the labels but obviously not the images

Comment: that would work too, just drop the string concat.  :-)  @(ViewBag.List[i]) is just as correct as the foreach.  The foreach is just prettier :-)

Comment: Cheers, I'll keep both in mind for the future, as they say, every day is a school day and I'm always happy to learn!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question you asked:

```
@foreach(string image in ViewBag.List)
{
    <img src="~/Images/@(image).jpg" />
}
```

But really you should be putting this into your model (not the ViewBag) and doing something similar where you iterate over the list in your model.  Additionally, `List` is a horrible name for a list of images.  You should maybe name that `images` instead.

Comment: Way to go... fix your post using mine ;-)  Good job.

Comment: I fixed it by testing it in a project, but thanks for your assumption.  I couldn't remember the exact syntax off the top of my head.  I upvoted your answer for being right if that makes you feel any better.

Comment: Psssst.. You don't need the ToString() either.  It's a dynamic, if it was assigned as a string it'll work.  Even if it wasn't a string upon assignment it will automatically use .ToString() :-D  Every object defines a .ToString() method which is automagically called when doing any form of string concatenation or used as a param in a String.Format(...) Using the inline .ToString() can potentially cause errors too... null.ToString() will throw a NullReferenceException, where @(null).jpg will only leave a broken image link.  So... There's other benefits.